# Vercel - Push automatically a file on my github repo (Next js)

Tags: github, vercel, next.js13

I have a vercel (Next project) that display some article (1K articles approximately) :

```
 article-11-12-2023.ts
 article-12-12-2023.ts
 article-13-12-2023.ts
```

I also have a custom api pages that generate a new article based on the day, i execute this api each day locally (myapp.com/api/generate-article)

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<any>
) {
  const getDailyArticleFormatted = generateArticle()

  fs.writeFile('customPath/article-${newDate()', getDailyArticleFormatted)

exec(
    `cd /customPath  && git add . && git commit -m "${gitMessage}" && git push`,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => ())

}
```

All this stuff works locally i execute the api once per day and it create an article push it on vercel and deploy the article correctly

I try to setup a cron that trigger `my myapp.com/api/generate-article` each day

But i have some error in the vercel logs

```
/bin/sh: git: command not found
```

Do you have an idea how to correctly setup my flow to push a new article everyday ? I don't really know if its the best deal to create file and push for an external serverless function

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want instead to take advantage of [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions), which can enable you to activate a `cron`... but on the GitHub server side. `git` should be available there!
See "[How can I use GitHub Actions with Vercel?](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-github-actions-with-vercel)"

- Create a `.yml` file in the `.github/workflows` directory of your GitHub repository.
- Define a workflow that runs on a schedule (cron job) to trigger your API.
- Use an action to commit and push the new file to your repository.

Change your API to return the generated article content instead of writing to a file and committing it.
The GitHub Action can use `curl` or any HTTP client to call your API. Use the response from the API to create a new file in your repository and commit it.

You new API endpoint:

```bash
Your-Nextjs-Project-Root
│   // other project files
└───pages
    └───api
        └───generate_article.js
```

With `pages/api/generate_article.js`:

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  // Replace 'YOUR_SECRET_TOKEN' with an environment variable for better security
  const secretToken = process.env.GITHUB_SECRET_TOKEN;

  if (req.headers['x-github-token'] !== secretToken) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
  }

  const getDailyArticleFormatted = generateArticle();
  res.status(200).send(getDailyArticleFormatted);
}
```

The API checks the `x-github-token` header against a secret token. Make sure you have set `GITHUB_SECRET_TOKEN` in your environment variables on Vercel.

For instance:

```bash
Your-Repository-Root
│   // other project files
└───.github
    └───workflows
        └───generate_article.yml
```

With `.github/workflows/generate_article.yml`:

```yaml
name: Generate and Commit New Article

on:
  schedule:
    # Runs at 00:00 UTC every day
    - cron: '0 0 * * *'

jobs:
  generate-article:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Generate New Article
        run: |
          ARTICLE_CONTENT=$(curl -s -H "x-github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_SECRET_TOKEN }}" https://myapp.com/api/generate-article)
          TODAY=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
          echo "$ARTICLE_CONTENT" > ./path/to/articles/article-$TODAY.ts

      - name: Commit and Push
        run: |
          git config --global user.name 'Your Name'
          git config --global user.email 'your-email@example.com'
          git add .
          git commit -m "Add new article for $TODAY"
          git push
```

The workflow runs on a schedule. You can set the schedule to run at a specific time every day (here at 00:00 UTC every day).